# What is the term/process name for creating a page by/for users on a website?

Tags: php, dynamic, server-side

I apologise for the poor explanation. What I mean is something like how stack overflow has a specific URL for each question that has been asked. When I am creating this question, is this a whole new page being added to the Stack Exchange domain? I would guess not but I don't understand the process. What is this called?

Lets say, I want to create a website where when a user is registered, there is a page that is created for them with `www.domain.com/user1` or something in that direction. What would I be required to learn to do this? I do not need specifics, but I simply don't know what this is 'called' in order to find out how to learn it!

I would assume at least, that It has something/a lot to do with php/server side scripting in general.

Comment: Notice on Stack Overflow that it's ignored for the most part. You can strip it off and keep just the ID part. Frameworks like Code Igniter make this easy to do. It's all dynamic, there's no real file sitting out there in a directory.

Comment: You need the term "Multipage"?

Its more like hosting?
The user visits your page, then she/he can create an account and upload the very own homepage - just usable from your domain, like `doamin.com/user1`?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ah I see. I did think that it wouldn't be saving all of the pages. Do you know what this process is called then, where you save a page, or ID, with information in that can be linked to as though it's a real page?

Comment: @Haudegen Not quite. I am making a page to show someone's stats in a game. So they would create an account and it would generate their stats based on their account information. Then, that page can be linked to anyone to show what their stats are like, if that makes sense?

Comment: Then you could try this:
Create something like: `profile.php` and in this php-file you can create a script, which will show the user stats (Maybe saved in a MySQL database) .. just add a userID, which you can add to the url, like: `profile.php?userID=1` ... after this, you can change the URL/Server behaviour with htaccess from `profile.php?userID=1` to `domain.com/user1`

Comment: Here is an example: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: @Haudegen Oh I see. So am I right in saying that you are simply pulling the user-specific information and putting it on the page. It is the same page every time, but with a different ID. So to a noob (me) it looks like it's a different page for different users?

Comment: You should define what you see as "page". If you mean a file on a system, then yes, it is probably 'the same page'. But there is no need to define a page like that. A page is a URI. you give an address to your browser, it sends it to a server, it sends you information back. So in that sense it is a different 'page', it's just generated by the same system (e.g. file).

Comment: @Nanne Sorry, by page I mean "stats.php" or something. So I would be showing all of the data via that 'page' with code bringing information in from elsewhere, thus changing the URL to something more unique. I have a bit of a warped sense of what a 'page' is because I'm very new. Page = something like "index.html" to me!

Comment: Yes, it is like that!
This is how it works!

There are many varietys how to do that, but the system is almost everytime the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

This process is called `URL Rewriting` and is done by adding Rewrite Rules to your `.htaccess` file (on a server called Apache, which I assume you are using. There are other ways to do URL Rewriting on Microsoft and Nginx servers; look it up).

You would put something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This rule uses regular expressions to catch any URL starting with "user" and ending in "some number" and sending that request to profile.php?id=*number*

And that's basically it. In the PHP file `profile.php` you access the ID using `$_GET['id']` just like you would if someone typed in `profile.php?id=99` except their URL looks like `/user99`

Comment: Most of the time, you just use one single rewrite that hides `index.php` from the url, then the remaining part is checked against a set of route rules [e.g. `/users/:id`, `/posts/:id/comments`, and so on], and that is handled by PHP rather than by Apache.

Comment: @moonwave99 yes many sites like Wordpress use a catch-all rewrite rule and then do the URL matching in PHP. I toned my answer to be a bit more specific to the question, and hopefully k4kuz0 can expand on the logic based on his needs.